# What do steps mean in the Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection-api

I would like to know what exactly does the term 'step' in the model's config file (while training a model) refer to in the Tensorflow Object Detection API. Can anyone please explain how it is related to an epoch and the number of steps per epoch?

Comment: steps represent the number of training iterations involved. For one complete cycle of data (epoch), the number of steps is the iterations on which the training and evaluation are performed.

Comment: A `step` is one operation to update the weights of the model. So the number of steps is exactly the number of times the weights will be updated by the optimizer (e.g. GradientDescent).

So when updating the weights, usually inputs are batched (or simply 1 input image as a batch), for each batched input, the weights are updated once. And when the input covers the complete dataset (the number of images), that is called one epoch.
 
As you can see, the number of steps per epoch is related to the dataset size and batch size.

Comment: So, a step is basically one weight update operation per batch, right? Say if I have 70,000 training images and a batch size of 32, the number of weight updations per epoch would be 70000/32 which roughly equals to 2188 and this is also equal to the number of steps per epoch, right?

Comment: yes, you are correct